# Aplicacion en C# inicie en Textbox en especifico

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Buen Dia,

Tengo esta pequeña duda, lo que pasa que al correr mi aplicación como se observa dentro de la imagen la inicia ya seleccionado un radiobutton.

Mi pregunta es:
¿Como puedo seleccionar para que al momento de correr la aplicación inicie en el textbox de nombre?

Si me podrían ayudar lo agradecería bastante.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: wpf o winforms?

Comment: Windows Forms es la que estoy utilizando.

Comment: Pudes establecer el foco en el control que quieres: nombreTextbox.Select(); nombreTextbox.Focus();

Comment: Luis, Muchas gracias igual me sirvió muchísimo tu respuesta. Saludos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dos formas, la primera con la propiedad TabIndex, puedes establecer el orden en el que los elementos reciben el foco.

Entonces puedes ponerle al TextoNombre / TabIndex = 0, (Desde las propiedades del objeto)
Luego puedes ponerle al siguiente objecto TabIndex = 1, al siguente TabIndex = 2, y así sucesivamente.

La segunda opción es en el evento Load() llamar la funcion Focus() del textbox
TextNombre.Focus()

Comment: Buen día Hugo, Muchísimas gracias justo lo que buscaba!

Comment: +1. Justo también lo que buscaba.